# Apple Promo Code limitation - What if I need many more than 50?

Tags: app-store-connect

I was hoping someone could suggest a good workaround for my situation.  I'm working for a website that has a very large subscriber base.  I am creating an iPhone app that the client would like to give to his paid subscribers for free, but allow non-subscribers to download from the app store for a fee.

I thought I would be able to offer promo codes to the subscribers, but I just discovered the limit on those is 50.  Any ideas on a good workaround there?

Comment: I would normally, but the entire app would only be accessible through the purchase.  Letting users download something for free, only to charge them before they can do anything is not only poor form but makes people angry, leading to a higher ration of bad reviews, etc.  Looking for a better method than this.

Comment: I cant see a better method than this. Good luck

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks!

Comment: You're violating your iTunes Connect agreement if you use promo codes for anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest releasing an enterprise version for all subscribers, this will allow for custom content, especially if they are paid subscribers.

Tutorial on doing that - [Distributing Enterprise Apps for iOS Devices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html)

This also allows for wireless downloads.

Then for the non subscribers, link them to the free version in the app store.

I think it makes the experience more personal for the paid subscribers too, if its a custom application distributed directly to them.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks, Helium3.  I think that's more in line with what I'm looking for.